# Substraer parámetros de una cadena URL PHP

Tags: php, php7, url, substring, preg-match

buenas noches. Estaba intentando realizar una función en PHP que me permitiera substraer las variables que se encuentran en los parámetros de una URL. Para esta función se debe introducir la URL cómo una cadena y substraer desde una posición a otra o aplicando una longitud.

Lo que quiero aplicar en mi proyecto sería lo siguiente:

```
$string = https://sub1.dominio.com/pagina.php?perfil=12345678~&imagen=123456&calidad=1080p&encoder=-zMfiy24~~

$perfil = 12345678
$imagen = 123456
$calidad = 1080p
$encoder = -zMfiy24~~
$subdominio = sub1
```

Cabe destacar lo siguiente, que el orden de los parámetros de la URL no debería de afectar la extracción, por ejemplo:

```
$string = https://sub1.dominio.com/pagina.php?perfil=12345678&imagen=123456&calidad=1080p&encoder=-zMfiy24~~

$string = https://sub1.dominio.com/pagina.php?imagen=123456&perfil=12345678&encoder=-zMfiy24~~&calidad=1080p

$perfil = 12345678
$imagen = 123456
$calidad = 1080p
$encoder = -zMfiy24~~
$subdominio = sub1
```

El parámetro "Encoder" (-zMfiy24~~) cuya longitud es de 10 carácteres siempre terminado en (~~) su parámetro en la URL podría variar, habría alguna manera de siempre extraerlo así el nombre del parámetro cambie? Por ejemplo

```
$string = https://sub1.dominio.com/pagina.php?code=-zMfiy24~~ ..............etc.......

$perfil = 12345678
$imagen = 123456
$calidad = 1080p
$encoder = -zMfiy24~~
$subdominio = sub1
```

Eso es lo que intento realizar.

Lo más cercano que encontré en internet fue la siguiente función:

```
    $String = "[modid=256]";

$First = "=";
$Second = "]";

$Firstpos=strpos($String, $First);
$Secondpos=strpos($String, $Second);

$id = substr($String , $Firstpos, $Secondpos);
```

Sería de gran ayudar recibir una mano con este algoritmo,

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Quizá te sea de utilidad el siguiente código:

```
$string = "https://sub1.dominio.com/pagina.php?perfil=12345678~&imagen=123456&calidad=1080p&encoder=-zMfiy24~~";
$full = parse_url($string, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$individual = explode("&", $full);
foreach ($individual as $val){
    var_dump(explode("=", $val));
}
```

Te dejo la documentación de `parse_url()` [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php)